# How to run shell script with hive action in an Oozie?

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, oozie

I am trying to run shell script with hive action every day in Oozie. I have succeded action in Oozie but hive part in shell script didn't work. When i run script from shell it works fine. Files located in HDFS.
Here is the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:341)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1420)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: GSS initiate failed
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:221)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
```

Here is my script

```
S=$(hive -S -hiveconf MY_VAR1=$DB -hiveconf MY_VAR2=$avgpay -hiveconf MY_VAR3=$Date_LastDay -hiveconf MY_VAR4=$Date_LastNmonth -f hv.hql)

`mysql ...`
S1=( $( for k in $S ; do echo $k ; done ) )
    cntn=${#S1[@]}
    for (( p=0 ; p<$cntn; p=p+5 ))
     do
     `mysql ...`
     done
```

Here is the workflow

```
<workflow-app name="shell-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" >
<start to="shellbpxp"/>
<action name="shellbpxp">
<shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
    <value>${queueName}</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
 <exec>netcool.sh</exec>
   <file>netcool.sh#netcool.sh</file>
   <file>hv.hql#hv.hql</file>
</shell>
 <ok to="end" />
<error to="fail" />
</action>
 <kill name="fail">
    <message>Script failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
 </kill>
<end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: Then credentials section was create in xml i have Error E0701 - "XML schema error"

Comment: Can you login to the Datanodes? There is a chance that the hive-site.conf has not been pushed out to the datanodes, and when you try to run hive shell commands from a datanode (which is what oozie will do) it will not work. Compare the hive-site.xml from a datanode with the hive-site.xml on you hadoop client node. I came across a problem like that before and that error looks similar. Why not run the hive script as a Hive action in Oozie?

Comment: Because i need a result of Hive script to parse it and write to mysql DB. I have hive-site.xml in HDFS, i take it from /etc/hive/conf. What should i compare?

Comment: I would try and get a hive-site.xml from one of the data nodes (often in /etc/hadoop/conf, but it could be somewhere else) and compare it to the hive-site.xml you put in hdfs. When you run a shell task, it will run on one of the data nodes, and then it will use the copy of hive-site.xml on the data node, not the one in HDFS. You might be able to achieve your objective with a hive step that saves the query result to hdfs and then a sqoop job to push that data into mysql.

Comment: I don't know how, but i fixed this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have hive-config.xml file as file parameter in your workflow.xml something like below:

```
<workflow-app name="shell-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" > 
<start to="shellbpxp"/> 
<action name="shellbpxp"> 
<shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">

   <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
   <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
   <job-xml>/user/<<your_path>>/hive-config.xml</job-xml> <configuration>  <property>
       <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
       <value>${queueName}</value>  </property> </configuration>  <exec>netcool.sh</exec>    <file>netcool.sh#netcool.sh</file>   
   <file>hv.hql#hv.hql</file>   
   <file>/user/<<your_path>>/hive-config.xml#hive-config.xml</file> </shell>  <ok to="end" /> <error to="fail" /> </action>  <kill
   name="fail">
       <message>Script failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>  </kill>
   <end name='end' /> </workflow-app>
```

You can find hive-config.xml file under your /etc/hive/conf directory. You need to comment out the fs.defaultFS node in hive-config.xml file.

hive-config.xml contains metastore-uris to connect to your database.

Answer (score 0):

add this after argument tag in workflow xml

```
<env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=${wf:user()}</env-var>
```

should work

Comment: Could you give some explanation with you answer please

Comment: The main error as you can see is about GSS, so there also might be some additional warnings about authorization method in system log, if we had it full before us. So the first step you should do is to show who is trying to get in, for example by this option. Also it could be helpful to run kinit with keytab inside shell script or to add credentials section inside the oozie-workflow xml.